# How do methods use hash arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, arguments

I saw hash arguments used in some library methods as I've been learning.

E.g.,

```
list.search(:titles, genre: 'jazz', duration_less_than: 270)
```

Can someone explain how a method uses arguments like this, and how you could create a method that makes use of Hash arguments?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Example:

```
def foo(regular, hash={})
    puts "regular: #{regular}"
    puts "hash: #{hash}"
    puts "a: #{hash[:a]}"
    puts "b: #{hash[:b]}"
end

foo("regular argument", a: 12, :b => 13)
```

I use `hash={}` to specify that the last argument is a hash, with default value of empty hash. Now, when I write:

```
foo("regular argument", a: 12, :b => 13)
```

It's actually a syntactic sugar for:

```
foo("regular argument", {a: 12, :b => 13})
```

Also, `{a: 12}` is syntactic sugar for `{:a => 12}`.

When all of this is combined together, you get a syntax that looks similar to named arguments in other languages.

Answer (score 37):

In Ruby 2.x, you can use `**` hash splat:

```
def foo( ordered_argument, **named_arguments )
  puts "Ordered argument: #{ordered_argument}"
  puts "Named arguments: #{named_arguments}"
end

foo( :titles, genre: 'jazz', duration_less_than: 270 )
#=> Ordered argument: titles
#=> Named arguments: {:genre=>"jazz", :duration_less_than=>270}
```

Answer (score 12):

When a Ruby method call's argument list ends in one or more key-value pairs, like `foo: 'bar'` or `'foo' => 1`, Ruby collects them all into a single hash and passes that hash as the last parameter. You can see that yourself in `irb`:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts foo: 'bar', baz: 'quux'
{:foo=>"bar", :baz=>"quux"}
=> nil
```

Thus, you can add a final, optional parameter to a method you're writing to receive this hash. You'll usually want to default it to an empty hash. You can call the parameter anything you want, but `options` is a common name:

```
def my_method(a, b, c, options = {})
  ...
end
```

One useful trick if you're using Rails: It's often handy to treat plain strings and symbols as equivalent. Rails adds a `symbolize_keys!` method to `Hash` to convert all string keys to symbols:

```
def my_method(a, b, c, options = {})
  options.symbolize_keys!
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Ruby 2.0 you can use keyword arguments <sup>[1][2]</sup> as opposed to the single Hash parameter.

```
def foo(keyword_arg: 'bar')
  keyword_arg
end
```

And here's how it behaves.

```
> foo
=> "bar"
> foo(keyword_arg: 'baz')
=> "baz"
```

1. http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments
2. http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/

Answer (score 2):

I would do one of two options:

1- if a got a large number of arguments to pass into a method I would use a hash like this:

```
some_method({titles => 'titulo', genre => 'jazz', duration_less_than => 270})
```

or

```
my_hash = {titles => 'titulo', genre => 'jazz', duration_less_than => 270}
some_method(my_hash)
```

and

```
def some_method(hash_options)
  #important code
end
```

2- option will be more 'traditional'

```
some_method('titulo', 'jazz', 270)

def some_method(titles, genre, duration_less_than)
#important code
end
```

Comment: This one enables multiline! Thanks for this @M.Octavio!    `some_method({titles => 'titulo', genre => 'jazz', duration_less_than => 270})`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

```
def my_method(title, args)
  puts title
  puts args
```

passing parameters:

```
my_method('test title', a: 'foo', b: 'bar')
  # => test title
  # => '{:a => 'foo', :b => 'bar'}
```