# Ruby default values error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was reading the source code of a gem "activerecord-postgres-earthdistance".

While running the migration script, it threw an error on the following method

```
def order_by_distance lat, lng, order: "ASC"
```

It gave an error for `order: "ASC"`

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
```

Isn't this valid Ruby syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 supports keywords arguments

```
[5] pry(main)> def bar(a: "name", b: "fem"); puts a,b end
[6] pry(main)> bar(a: "John", b: "Male")
John
Male
[7] pry(main)> bar("John", "Male")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
from (pry):5:in `bar'
```

However the above is not valid in 1.9 see below:

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
[2] pry(main)> def bar(a: "name", b: "fem"); puts a,b end
SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting $end
def bar(a: "name", b: "fem"); puts a,b end
              ^
[2] pry(main)> def bar(a: "name"); puts a end
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting $end
def bar(a: "name"); puts a end
              ^
```

For better understanding you can read [here](http://magazine.rubyist.net/?Ruby200SpecialEn-kwarg) and [here](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
def order_by_distance(lat, lng, hash={})
  puts hash[:order]
end

=> order_by_distance(lat, lng, order: "ASC")
=> "ASC"
```

[use hash arguments in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576477/how-do-functions-use-hash-arguments-in-ruby)

Comment: I tried that too

    def foo( a, b: "ASC")
      puts "runs"
    end

It gives the error `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end`

Comment: what `ruby` version you use?

Comment: `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: `def foo( a, b: "ASC") puts "runs" end` inline?

Comment: for inline use need `def foo( a, b: "ASC"); puts "runs"; end`

Comment: Here are the full stack error

`earth_distance.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
def foo( a, b: "ASC" )
              ^
earth_distance.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end`

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576477/how-do-functions-use-hash-arguments-in-ruby)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42705/discussion-between-junaidkirkire-and-monk-code)