# Application_Controller.rb render method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def hello
        render html: 'Hello World!'
    end
end
```

I have this defined in my application_controller.rb file and I'm just trying to figure out what the "html: 'Hello World!'" syntax is. Is this like a hash passed to the render method?

Comment: It is the same as `render({html: 'Hello World'})` if that helps

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do methods use hash arguments in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576477/how-do-methods-use-hash-arguments-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

It’s html that gets shown to the user when they go to that specific route. For your instance it might be something like `/hello`. To answer your question yes it’s a hash and you can render other options such as JSON and XML.

You can check out the api docs for all the different options and syntax https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render